# How to create custom page and show it in menu in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel with Laravel Nova for the admin panel. I want to have a page that shows user settings from **app/config/some_config.php** file.

So, how I can add a custom page(without a model) and show a link for this page in the admin panel with a new group(when we create a new resource, we must set $model and $group)?

Comment: you have to create [custom tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html)..this will create a sidebar menu and view and you can show whatever you want in that view.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon you are right. Thank you. 
p.s can't accept comment as answer.

Comment: no problem..if you want a detailed answer, just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tool feature for Nova Projects. Just run the command:

`php artisan nova:tool nameofyourtool`

> https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html

Comment: How can create the sub pages in side that tool?

Answer (score -1):

You should create the menu in theme/layout.blade.php by adding code from a regular .blade.php file that describes your menu item and after that you should use the Vue component `<router-link :to="{name: "here is the name of the Vue component" }">`  This is the best way i have found so far. Its a solution